# Is this the way to obtain the same individuals for x_test and y_test?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

```
x_train, x_test = train_test_split(x, test_size = 0.3,random_state=250)
y_train, y_test = train_test_split(y, test_size = 0.3,random_state=250)
```

Is this the way to coincide the same individuals in `x_test` and `y_test` as well as `x_train` and `y_train`?

Comment: why don‘t you check this on your own by a minimal example and/or by seeing the docs https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: @Peter, we are about collecting questions and answers that are easily searchable.  A link to the documentation is rarely what we are trying to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`train_test_split` has this capability built-in.  Just pass all of the data in the first go like:

#### Code:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=250)
```

#### Test Code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x = list(range(100))
y = list(range(100, 200))
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=250)

assert(all(xx == yy - 100 for xx, yy in zip(x_train, y_train)))
assert(all(xx == yy - 100 for xx, yy in zip(x_test, y_test)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using indices to split the dataset into train and test for both features and targets.

Comment: How does this answer the question?